# Word like tactful and diplomatic

Tags: single-word-requests

Its a word I've forgotten, but its a way of describing someone which is tactful and diplomatic. Like "Instead of saying she's quick to anger, I would say she's passionate, which is a _____ way of describing her."

Answer (score 2):

> "Instead of saying she's quick to anger, I would say she's passionate,
>   which is a **charitable** way of describing her."

**charitable**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/charitable)

> lenient or forbearing in judging others

As in:

The disagreement was described **charitably** as a “frank discussion,” but witnesses described it as a knock down-drag out shouting match.

Answer (score 0):

**Euphemistic**? [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/euphemistic) defines that as:

> the substitution of an agreeable or inoffensive expression for one
>   that may offend or suggest something unpleasant

Answer (score 0):

**Polite?**

[Definition:] (https://www.thefreedictionary.com/polite)

> Marked by or showing consideration for others and observance of accepted social usage.

That sounds like diplomatic or tactful.

[Here](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/polite?s=t) are some other options that might work.